# Broken links in /dev/disk/by-path

Tags: udev, usb-drive, block-device

I work with a lot of low quality USB flash memory modules - some of them can even hang the USB controller and block all traffic until I remove them.

I'm testing these drives using `f3` and a custom Bash script to make it suitable for mass production.

My script uses /dev/disk/by/path links to make it possible to link physical location in a USB hub to an entry on the screen.

Sometimes I have broken links in /dev/disk/by-path - I also noticed that lsblk might list drives that have already been removed,and Dolphin file manager lists removable drives that are long gone (physically disconnected).

Is there anything I can do something to clean up these broken symlinks without rebooting the system?

I've also asked a possibly related question:
[Multiple links in /dev/disk/by-path pointing to the same /dev/sd* device files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474746/multiple-links-in-dev-disk-by-path-pointing-to-the-same-dev-sd-device-files)

Comment: You can reset the USB root controller (google), that should re-enumerate all USB devices. If during this process the broken symlinks don't get removed (only you can test that), write a script that removes them before resetting the controller.

Comment: Could you please link a specific solution to resetting the USB root controller? I've tried resetting the individual ports by issuing unbind/bind commands, but it didn't work. Also: should I manually `rm` broken links in /dev/disk/by-path? Is that safe?

Comment: Quick googling finds e.g. [this](https://www.linux.org/threads/resetting-the-usb-subsystem.10404/), around Figure 7 (use the correct controller instead of ohci). Yes, it's safe to remove symlinks in `/dev/disk`, and yes, you must manually remove them if your `udev` rules don't remove them automatically.